# Flex / CSS Div won't grow 100% of parent height

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am using flex and have 2 columns. These items both fill all height available.

Inside item 1 I've added 2 div's ... the second one I need it to fill up all space available and scroll Y if items inside it go overflow.

I cannot get .box to go 100% height of it's parent.

Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <div class="container">
      <div class="item">
        <div class="title">Title here</div>
        <div class="box">
          Box Here
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item"></div>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 98vh;
}

.item {
  flex: 1;
}

.item:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: blue;
}

.item:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: red;
}

.title {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: white;
}

.box {
  background-color: grey;
  height: 100%; /* not working */
  align-self: stretch;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this css:

```
.container {
    min-height: 98vh;
}

.flex {
    /* display: flex; */
    /* flex-direction: column; */
    height: 98vh;
}

.item {
    /* flex: 1; */
    height: 50%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.item1 {
    background-color: blue;
}

.item2 {
    background-color: red;
}

.title {
    font-size: 30px;
    color: white;
    background: blue;
}

.box {
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background-color: grey;
}
```

No need to use flex and complicate the problem

Comment: I have a problem here. It works great one the first item but I can only have one item...I'm going to be adding multiple items

Comment: It works fine when you add as many `<div>test</div>` as you want if that's what you were referring to

Comment: Yes, but I can only use the box once?

Answer (score 0):

I changed the HTML layout a little bit. You can use flex.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="title">Title here</div>
        <div class="flex">
            <div class="item item1">
                <div class="box">
                    <div>
                        test
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        test
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        test
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item item2"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
.container {
    min-height: 98vh;
}

.flex {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 98vh;
}

.item {
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.item1 {
    background-color: blue;
}

.item2 {
    background-color: red;
}

.title {
    font-size: 30px;
    color: white;
    background: blue;
}

.box {
    background-color: grey;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    flex: 1;
}
```

Comment: That is perfect until you add any divs to the inside of the .box div. If you add for example: <div>test</div>
          <div>test</div>
          <div>test</div>
          <div>test</div> the grey area just grows and it's height is not longer the same. I need it to stay the same height when I add div's to .box

Comment: @pixelKus2022 It works for me, see this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Pavel40/3n1f8o5d/) for complete html with css.

Comment: If you take off the "<div>test</div> <div>test</div> <div>test</div> <div>test</div>" from inside .box ... you'll see the red and blue .item div's height. they are both the same height. Then when you add the <div>test</div> <div>test</div> <div>test</div> <div>test</div> you .box (grey) div will grow in height. I need it to stay the same height as it was before adding the content

Comment: Is this not possible to do?

Comment: I fixed my answer. I had to change the HTML layout so that the title is not inside the flex container. I think it works the way you wanted now.

Comment: The overflow-y: scroll is not working on .box

Comment: The other answer has a better solution to the problem. I think you should use that instead of my flex based solution.